# Missing required parameters for [Route: tags.update] [URI: tags/{tag}]. (View: /home/alex/Desktop/laravel/cms/resources/views/tags/create.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the above error and i think the problem is here , but i cannot figure out why

```
<form action="{{ isset($tag) ? route('tags.update', $tag->id) : route('tags.store') }}" method="POST">
```

Here is the create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">
            {{ isset($tag) ? 'Edit Tag' : 'Create Tag'}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        @if($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
               <ul class="list-group">
                   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li class="list-group-item text-danger">
                            {{ $error }}
                        </li>
                   @endforeach
                </ul> 
            </div>
        @endif

        <form action="{{ isset($tag) ? route('tags.update', $tag->id) : route('tags.store') }}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            @if(isset($tag))
                @method('PUT')          
            @endif
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ isset($tag) ? $tag->name : '' }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success">
                    {{ isset($tag) ? 'Update Tag' : 'Add Tag' }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Here is the TagsContrloler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Tags\CreateTagRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Tags\UpdateTagRequest;

class TagsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('tags.index')->with('tags', Tag::all());
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('tags.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(CreateTagRequest $request)
    {

        Tag::create([
            'name' => $request->name
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Tag created succesfully.');

        return redirect(route('tags.index'));

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Tag $category)
    {
        return view('tags.create')->with('tag', $category);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateTagRequest $request, Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->update([
            'name' => $request->name
        ]);

        session()->flash('success', 'Tag updated succesfully.');
        return redirect(route('tags.index'));
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Tag $tag)
    {
        $tag->delete();
        session()->flash('success', 'Tag deleted succesfully');
        return redirect(route('tags.index'));
    }
}
```

and here is the web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();



Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::resource('categories', 'CategoriesController');

    Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController');
    
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
    
    Route::get('trashed-posts', 'PostsController@trashed')->name('trashed-posts.index');
    
    Route::put('restore-post/{post}','PostsController@restore')->name('restore-posts');
});
```

Comment: `route('tags.update', ['tag' => $tag->id])` . Please use the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: yes that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `$category` to `$tag` in the `edit()` method of the controller. When you write the class name next to variable in your controller, you're telling laravel to use its model binding functionality, and laravel need the exact name of the resource which is defined in the route to connect it to the correct model instance. Refer to [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding)

You're using `Route::resource('tag', ...)`, and it creates the route of `Route::get('tag/edit/{tag}', ...)` in it. So, you need to refer to **tag** exactly in your controller.

```php
public function edit(Tag $tag)
{
    return view('tags.create', compact('tag'));
}
```